# Android: prevent background color from changing toward the edge of a shape

Tags: android, user-interface, colors, drawable, shapes

I need to create white rectangle shape with red border (width `1px`) and another red rectangle attached to it from below. Like this:

[image]

White rectangle will be `EditText` while red border and red rectangle will appear in order to notify the user about input errors. Nothing fancy.

I have already tried several approaches, but none of them looked good due to the same reason - the color changes towards the edge of a shape (looks like the outermost pixels are the ones that change). The issue can be seen in this magnified picture:

[image]

The hierarchy on this particular snapshot is `LinearLayout` with red background and `padding` of `1px`, but I observed the same effect while attempted to use other approaches as well (including drawing the border around `EditText` programmatically).

This effect looks like the standard of Android, and my question is how can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody stumbles upon this question - the described behavior was some emulator related artifact. On real devices the colors were just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check following example, hope it will help you.

rect_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#EF9A9A"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

</shape>
```

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:lines="3"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#EF9A9A"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="#EF5350"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the opposite from what I need - I want to have solid, monolithic color, without any distinguishable "border"

Comment: hi Vasiliy please explain what you want exactly, I'm not getting.